# Problem to recreate the parser function "many" in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I try to create a calculator and I create some functions for the parsing

I already create a type `type Parser a = String -> Maybe (a , String )` and a function that take a Char as argument and returns a Parser Char like this :

```
parse1 :: Char -> Parser Char
parse1 b (a:as)
  | b == a = Just (b, as)
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

and I would like to create a function which takes a parser in argument and tries to apply it zero or more times, returning a list
of the parsed elements.

```
many :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
> many (parse1 ' ') "    lopesbar"
Just ("    ", "lopesbar")
```

I Already try this but it doesn't work (infinite loop)

```
many :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
many _ [] = Nothing
many func1 s =
  case func1 s of
    Just _ -> many func1 s
    Nothing -> Nothing
```

also i try this

```
many :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
many func1 s = case func1 s of
    Just (f, a) -> Just ([f], a)
    Nothing -> Nothing
```

there are no errors but it's not the same output

Comment: What is your question? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? If not, how does the output differ from what you want instead?

Comment: Please [edit] the encountered errors to into your question.

Comment: "but I get an error" What's the error message? Do note that none of the branches in your code ever return a `Just` result, so that's not right, but that shouldn't cause an error.

Comment: @Zeta I just want to recode the function many with another parameter like my type ```Parser a``` and as error I have a infinite loop in my code
many :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
many _ [] = Nothing
many func1 s =
  case func1 s of
    Just _ -> many func1 s
    Nothing -> Nothing

Comment: Hint: in the `Just x` case, use another `case` to inspect the result of the recursive call. Hint2: you can't recurse with the exact same arguments, that will cause infinite recursion.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem, but I urge you not to use a type synonym to represent a parser; it will only end up confusing you later on. Instead, write something like `newtype Parser a = Parser { unParser :: String -> Maybe (a , String ) }`. Now you'll have a much more definite idea of just where the parsers are supposed to be. And later, you'll want to be able to write `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Alternative`, and `Monad` instances for `Parser`, which you can only do if it's a proper first-class type.